# Почему не закрыт запятой обособленный причастный оборот перед тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

По общим правилам обособленный оборот должен обособляться двумя запятыми:

***Маленький Дорн, живущий рядом с ходом — это феноменальное совпадение***! То есть, конечно, ничего страшного не было бы, если б вы жили и в другом районе, но я верю в великий смысл совпадений! (Б. Акунин)

**Почему же нет второй запятой?** Ошибка корректора? Авторская пунктуация? Если так, то в чем ее смысл? Встречается ли в других текстах такое оформление?

Comment: А что за ход? Не могу найти в словарях.

Comment: Книгу почитайте. "Детская книга". Жанр: фантастика, исторический детектив, остросюжетный и очень познавательный по части истории, в том числе истории языка. Много слов и выражений эпохи Смутного времени. Акунин историю хорошо знает, так что как будто побываете там вместе с мальчиком.. А "ход" - это хронодыра, переход  в другое время. Очень маленького размера, поэтому пролезть может только ребенок до 12 лет.  По сюжету он должен принадлежать роду крестоносца Тео фон Дорна, то есть быть маленьким Дорном. А то, что он живет в доме  с нужным ходом, - это счастливая случайность.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что здесь нет ошибки.

При изъятии оборота между подлежащим и сказуемым предложение должно оставаться корректным:
*Маленький Дорн — это феноменальное совпадение!* || В таком предложении вообще нет логики. Персонаж не может являться совпадением. Значит, часть после тире относится не к подлежащему.

Часть после тире относится именно к причастному обороту. То есть феноменальное совпадение в том, что живёт рядом с ходом. Тем более что в следующем предложении эта феноменальность разъясняется. Сама часть после тире, на мой взгляд, является вставкой, например:
*Маленький Дорн, живущий рядом с ходом — это феноменальное совпадение! — способен на многое.*

Comment: Сомневаюсь, однако.  Это вроде  обычный определительный оборот, отнесенный к подлежащему. Таки конструкции часто встречаются, но везде обособление с двух сторон делается. Кстати, недавно парочку таких предложений проверяла. У автора запятой не было, но я решила не напрягаться, а поставить. Теперь вот сомневаюсь. А конкретное правило на эту тему или хотя бы примеры у Розенталя/Лопатина есть? По какому правилу обособляем? О независимой постановке знаков?

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что это присоединительная конструкция? Вряд ли это кому докажешь.

Comment: Если поставить запятую, то получается, что маленький Дорн является совпадением. Давать такое определение персонажу не корректно по всем параметрам. Совпадение - это не человек, а какой-то факт. А сам факт находится в причастном обороте. А часть после тире как бы комментирует оборот.

Comment: Смысл получается такой: Маленький Дорн, живущий рядом с ходом! Это феноменальное совпадение!  Постпозитивный номинатив. Но у Розенталя такие предложения (с оценкой) рассматриваются в теме: Разоружение — веление времени. А про обособление определительных оборотов после подлежащего информации нет. Вероятно, в разных случаях решение может быть разным.

Comment: Можно и так трактовать. Но если оформлять одним предложением, то правильнее отнести к обороту, чем к подлежащему. Решение в таких случаях должно основываться на корректности определения понятия (говорить, что Дорн - совпадение, не корректно). Другое дело: *Маленький Дорн живёт рядом с ходом - это феноменальное совпадение* (но всё равно то, что живёт там, а не то, что он Дорн).